# Pull Records every 90 days in SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I fetch records every 90 days based on criteria in a case statement?

```
SELECT
    LB.bayview_loan_number Loan_Number,
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, OL.LOAN_ADDED_DT, PH3.SKIPTR) >= 120 
          AND DATEDIFF(day, OL.LOAN_ADDED_DT, GETDATE()) > 150 
          AND Con2.LastCon IS NULL THEN **--repeat this step every 90 days** 'LMSKIP' 
    END AS ST
FROM 
    CAPMKTS.dbo.Loan_Bayview LB
INNER JOIN 
    LDG.dbo.LDG_ORIGINAL_LOAN OL ON LB.bvln = OL.ln_no
```

Comment: A query alone can't re-issue itself periodically.  You'd need something that issues the query.  A SQL job, an application, etc.

Comment: Are you in the CG office?  Come over to the 4th floor, we can talk about it ;)

Comment: @KevinSuchlicki, you guys are collegue? WOW! Amazing.

Comment: @Rahul LOL, yes.  I recognize the field names.

Comment: Best bet for you, pull your SQL query in a stored procedure and then schedule that SP to run every 90 days period.

Comment: Hahaha,everyone who has a problem telports directly to stackoverflow.

Comment: To the newuser, First: Welcome to SO. Again a piece of advice, if it's organization sensitive; don't put the same code in thread; as you can see your other colleague can recognize it by seeing the code itself.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to run SQL process on a timed basis is [by creating scheduled jobs in the SQL Server Agent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx).

Comment: OR Manually; TO DO Item after every 90 days :)

Comment: @Rahul: Good suggestion for times when it's not too critical to make sure the process runs at a precise time. I could see that working in some situations where a user might ask for a scheduled job.